# Thread sleep function Not responding

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading

In my `ASP.NET` web page (`C#`) I want to execute one function every half an hour so i am using the following code

```
while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1800000);
    checkstatus();
}
```

I want to know whether this thread is sleeping half an hour or not. Or Is there any expiry time for `Thread.Sleep()`.

If i give 60000 instead of 1800000 the code is working for me. Can any one tell me why it is not responding for  Thread.Sleep(1800000); means it is not executing the `checkstatus()`?

Comment: A timer would be a much nicer way of doing this!

Comment: In web form? i want only one process need to execute. So how can i use timer? when i have to start?

Comment: Why do you need your thread to sleep for such a long time. If it is to run a process every 30 minutes, then a windows service might be a more suitable way of approaching this.

Comment: ya i heard this but i am not knowing how to use that... any Help?

Comment: [Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application in the Component Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: [How to: Create Windows Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks alot i'll try this. and let you know.

Comment: @Chris Hammond The above mentioned link is to create windows services how to install that service in https://bh-plesk-web4.webhostbox.net Cpnel? windows hosting?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46518/discussion-between-chris-hammond-and-raghuveera)

Answer (score 4):

IIS is probably shutting down your worker process... The default value is set at 20 minutes.

[image: Advance Settings of App Pool in IIS 7]

Comment: Whether in domain also it is same?

Comment: I am asking with you that i have uploaded this to server. Whether in server also this time is same?

Comment: Sorry, I am unsure what you are saying.... The image aboive is from my server to show example. On your web server, check to application pool settings and look for something like "Idle Time-out"... it is probably set at 20 minutes. However, as annotated in the comments under your question, it is probably not a best approach to block for 30m in a web app.

Comment: I don't agree on your point if there is any active instance in above case is thread then it should not recycle? Am I right.

Comment: I guess it depends on what IIS interprets as "Idle"... In effect, the app IS idle because the thread has been put to sleep. But, as you say, the instance of the page has not been destroyed as the thread is still "running" (albeit asleep).

Comment: The definition __[idleTimeout] Amount of time (in minutes) a worker process will remain idle
before it shuts down. A worker process is idle if it is not processing requests and no
new requests are received.__. Is a sleeping thread considered "processing" is then the question.

Comment: @Chris Hammond  i am having windows server in https://bh-plesk-web4.webhostbox.net Control panel this application pool option is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Set an object in cache to expire every 30 mins. Check if this cache object exists, if not, 30 mins expire so do your logic, and, in finally set cache object again. Sorry for wording.

Comment: But if the work process is recycling after 20m, then the cache would be lost, so this would not work either.

Comment: Yes, sorry I see your answer after I wrote. It is true. I would like to know if this was the cause of problem. Thanks.